# Can we change the autowired of a parent bean in a child constructor javaspring?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

i have an issue with the annotation in Spring. I can't seems to update the object with the @Qualifier annotation. Lets make an abridged version of my problem :

Lets say i have a parent java class looking like this :

```
public class test {

 @Autowired
    protected object x;
}
```

A child class extending the parent using a constructor like this :

```
public class testChild extends test {

    @Autowired
public testChild(@Qualifier("y") Object y) {
        this.x = y;
    }
```

And 2 Bean, one with the @Primary annotation and another one with the @Bean(Name="y").

The Bean with the @Primary annotation always seems to be applied since the parent has the autowired without qualifier specified and the bean i receive in the constructor is also the primary, is there a way to get the bean @Qualifier("y") with the child class without modifying the parent class?

Answer (score 0):

not the way you want it, no - solution is to stop using `@Primary` and use only `@Qualifier`s everywhere instead. Or you can use `@Profile` for creating different beans for different profiles. But whenever you use @Primary it becomes the primary bean, that is kind of the point of the annotation.

Comment: i feel like i'll still hit the same issue since i want the `@Qualifier` to change in the child, not the parent. The parent class has approximatly 7 children which all use the @Primary bean correctly but 1 new class have to call a different instance of the bean

Comment: try removing @Autowired from the parent if parent is not instantiated directly.